# Meaning of high nibble written to NES MMC3 bank data register

Tags: roms

In part of my disassembly of the European version of Dragon's Lair for the NES (which uses the MMC3 mapper chip):

```
    LDA #$32            ; EA00: A9 32
    LDX #$06            ; EA02: A2 06
    STX LABEL_8000      ; EA04: 8E 00 80
    STA LABEL_8001      ; EA07: 8D 01 80
    LDY #$00            ; EA0A: A0 00
    LDA LABEL_0312      ; EA0C: AD 12 03
```

I can see that the value written to the [bank data register](https://www.nesdev.org/wiki/MMC3#Bank_data_.28.248001-.249FFF.2C_odd.29) (subsequent to writing  `0x06` to the [bank select register](https://www.nesdev.org/wiki/MMC3#Bank_select_($8000-$9FFE,_even)) to select the PRG mapping) is far beyond the number of program code banks, i.e, this particular ROM has 16 PRG banks, each of 8k and this snippet appears to be selecting the 51st bank.

Clearly my understanding is incomplete; when tested in [an emulator with debugging](https://www.mesen.ca/), this seems to show that the high nibble of the value is discarded (or that the number is treated modulo 16, the same calculation in this scenario).

Additionally, it doesn't appear to be an optimisation with an eye to use the value in `A` later, as this is overwritten by the `LDA` at `0xEA0C`.

I can find the same high nibble being used [in](https://github.com/captainsouthbird/smb3/blob/master/PRG/prg031.asm#L1516-L1517) [this](https://github.com/captainsouthbird/smb3/blob/master/PRG/prg031.asm#L1547-L1548) [disassembly](https://github.com/captainsouthbird/smb3/blob/master/PRG/prg031.asm#L1620-L1621) of Super Mario Bros 3, which also uses the MMC3 mapper, also in situations where the `A` register is overwritten immediately afterwards.

In my searching I haven't found anything that documents this behaviour, so I'd like to know if these high order bits have some purpose, for example to configure the mapper in some additional way; it strikes me as unlikely that venerable NES programmers would simply set these high bits haphazardly.

Comment: As this is entirely a programming question, and an assembly one at that, I'd guess this is better suited to stack overflow. Oddly, I am able to read it since I know 6502 assembly from my C64 work in the 80s. :)

Comment: Hey @Almo, I had the draft all ready on SO and then thought to myself "hmm, isn't this more of a game dev question?" :) I'll leave it here for now, see if anyone has any insight, but then I may cross post onto SO ✌️

Comment: Warning that crossposts are frowned upon. If you put it on SO, I think the etiquette is to delete it here.

Comment: retrocomputing.stackexchagne.com could also be an option, considering that we are talking about a legacy platform here.

Comment: It does seem odd that it would have been set accidentally. And I've seen some rather unusual uses of undocumented features on that hardware - this might be an instance of deliberately doing something out of spec. Are those instructions unique to the EU version?

Comment: @Almo yep, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @Pikalek with more testing under Mesen with SMB3, both PAL and NTSC versions store the same values to 0x8001, with the high nibble set, so it appears to not be region hardware specific.